# Help identifying a 5-pin (4 ground, one signal) connector

Tags: rf, connector

I bought a dev-kit for a piece of equipment, and it came with some optional outputs. Two of them don't have a connector, and I'm having difficulty identifying what they should be. The holes form a 2x2 mm square for each output (PPS and EVENT).

[image: mistery pin]

I thought it could be a female MCX, but the outside holes are circular, not square. Has anybody ever seen them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good luck getting anyone to make square holes in a PCB. The connector itself may have square legs, but the holes you solder them into are always round.

<strike>You're probably correct about them being for MCX jacks</strike> Edit: I was thinking of MMCX--MCX is larger than this. Try a Molex 734140170 or similar! If one fits, solder it in there and use it.

Really, you could solder any connector you like in there as long as it has four outer legs with the correct spacing and a single inner pin. Can't be bothered to look it up right now, but you may be able to get through-hole SSMA or similar connectors with that pin spacing too. The exact type of connector used doesn't matter, as long as it fits in the footprint and can handle the appropriate frequencies.

Comment: You're right about the "square hole"! I was thinking of something like this:
https://www.raypcb.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/slot-pcb.jpg

In any case, SMA, SSMA, or MCX won't fit. The spacing for all three is larger than the 2 mm.

Comment: @Marco I'd also recommend looking into the dev kit's manuals, to see if a particular part number is mentioned. It may just say "Use Molex/Amphenol/Cinch/whoever part number (whatever)".

Comment: @Marco Also, I was thinking of MMCX (outer pin spacing usually--but not always!--2.54 mm) when I read MCX. Does a Molex 734140170 fit?

Comment: MMCX sounds like a good candidate. I didn't know this one. I'll order a couple and give it a try. It's not a super sensitive circuit, so a little bit of filing won't hurt.

Comment: MMCX just arrived, they're the correct ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the functionality of the board, it could be an [SMA RF connector](https://www.soselectronic.com/products/various/sma-p-61249):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This does look identical to MCX, backed up by the silkscreen. PPS is a precise time-keeping interrupt from GPS/GNSS that is quite useful for synchronising events on systems that have a latency in the comms between them. The event line could then be for alignment of the actual data the board is accepting, but only the manufacturer or documentation will know for sure.

The radius should be wider than the width of the square legs, so you shouldn't have an issue, though you should still consult the datasheet before buying connectors.

Comment: PPS doesn't have to be from satnav systems. It just stands for "pulse per second", and knowing nothing about this board, it could just be a divided-down output from a crystal oscillator.

Comment: This is one of those aftermarket parts where the manufacturer (JINYUSHI Wireless) is unresponsive. They also don't provide a datasheet. This board is just an op-amp for a time sync signal with some LEDs and other small things. Pretty simple and cheap but requires some investigation as to which pin to use.